# MongoDB Index Ops Not Increasing When Index is Query's Winning Plan

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB for a project, and I've created indexes for faster operations in MongoDB itself. The previous deployment on a platform shows that the indexes are used, but when I tried running the project locally, even when I query using Mongo shell client, the index ops count are always 0.

This is weird since when I explain my query in Mongo shell client, the index is used and the scan is `IXSCAN`, which indicates that the query uses index. However, the index ops count is still 0.

The index is given below:

```js
> db.users.aggregate([{$indexStats: {}}])
{ "name" : "I_E_D", "key" : { "email" : 1, "deleted" : 1 }, "host" : "HOST:27017", "accesses" : { "ops" : NumberLong(1), "since" : ISODate("2020-02-08T00:52:43.303Z") } }
```

The query is below:

```
> db.users.find({$and: [{"email":"admin@admin.com"}, {deleted:false}]}).explain()
```

And the explained query is given below:

```js
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "sample.users",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "deleted" : {
                                                "$eq" : false
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "email" : {
                                                "$eq" : "admin@admin.com"
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "email" : 1,
                                        "deleted" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "I_E_D",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                        "email" : [ ],
                                        "deleted" : [ ]
                                },
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 2,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "email" : [
                                                "[\"admin@admin.com\", \"admin@admin.com\"]"
                                        ],
                                        "deleted" : [
                                                "[false, false]"
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "HOST",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "4.0.0",
                "gitVersion" : "3b07af3d4f471ae89e8186d33bbb1d5259597d51"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

So what is the problem? Why is my index said to not be used (ops = 0)?

Comment: Is the database server process being restarted at all? (Results are re-set following a restart). If you run the query a few times without explain, does `$indexStats` show what you would expect?

Comment: Ah shoot that's right. When I ran the query without explain the index ops increments. Thanks @AdamHarrison